# hostname configuration for remote access

Tags: network, ssh

I have a new Mac Pro that's running Mavericks and I would like to configure it for remote access (ssh and sftp).  The IT staff says I need to provide them with a fully qualified domain name before we can proceed.  So what I need to do is set hostname.subdomain.domain.com.  I've seen some posts about setting hostnames, but what about the rest of this?

Comment: I take it your domain name details are provided by your IT department, and you merely wish to understand how to apply them? Is the Mac internal to a work infrastructure, and you want to remotely access it from home, or the other way round?  Just do we can understand the topology and direction of access. If you can add more detail and clarify it would help.

Comment: Is your Mac Pro connected directly to your internet provider's router or is it sitting behind a home gateway type router? This question needs more details to be answerable in some succinct way.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and type or copy & paste this bash one-liner:

```
 echo; MyExtIPAddrIs=`curl -s echoip.org`; host -4 $MyExtIPAddrIs|cut -c 22-100; hostname; echo
```

Your fully qualified domain name will appear after the words "domain name pointer" in the line that is output, and continues and includes, after the period at the far right, your mac's internal network address appearing on the next line.

Comment: Isn't that just the local network name though?  I need a hostname that's going to be connected to an IP address that will be accessible from off site.

Comment: @user2379888 running `host -4 $(curl -s echoip.org)` gives you a fully qualified name (`178-83-159-12.dynamic.hispeed.ch` in my case) which should be enough for your IT staff. The name is dynamic though, if your provider doesn't offer static IP addresses you will need to redo this every time your IP changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Sharing Preferences Pane in System Preferences. At the top, underneath "Computer Name" should be a sentence in small type that gives you that qualified name for your local network. You can also get this by opening /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and typing the command `hostname -f` and hitting return.

---

If you are planning on remote accessing your home machine, you can achieve remote access simply by using your external Internet IP address which you can get from a web service like http://whatsmyip.org or using the command `curl echoip.org` in terminal when you're at home. Then, when remote, from the Finder, under the Go menu choose "Connect to Server" or type <kbd>command-k</kbd> and enter `vnc://the.ip.address.here` and hit return, and this will open up a screen sharing session with whatever machine is port forwarded 5900 at your router.

But if your IT staff insists on having your fully qualified domain name, you can get thet using the following instructions:

Open Terminal and type or copy & paste this compound command:

```
 MyExtIPAddrIs=`curl -s echoip.org`; host -4 $MyExtIPAddrIs
```

Your fully qualified domain name will appear after the words "domain name pointer" in the line that is output, and excludes the final period ( . ) at the far right.

---

Please note: giving this domain name pointer to your IT staff will not be all that is necessary to achieve remote access. You will need to [open the default remote access port to forward the remote access port](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1882?viewlocale=en_US) in your router to your computer's internal network IP address or hostname.

1. This is achieved by using [telnet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/telnet.1.html) or a [browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser) to access the router's configuration pages. You can get your router's local network address by looking in your Network Preference Pane in System Preferences (once you select the proper interface on the left, perhaps having to hit the advanced button and clicking the TCP/IP tab, the IP of your router will be listed as `Router:` there).
2. Open a browser and enter `http://` or `https://` and follow it without spaces with your router's internal network address that you just retrieved from Network Preferences. You will likely need your router's admin user name and password. This will be at the default settings if you haven't already set this up, and you can google search for your router's exact model name/number and "default admin name and password" to find out what that is, or call your ISP and ask them for it.
3. Once in your router's firewall configuration pages, you need to port forward the port that remote desktop uses. For [Apple Remote Desktop](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6175?viewlocale=en_US) (and VNC), that port is 5900. So for any incoming requests from the Internet side of your router, you need to port forward 5900 to your computer's internal network address or internal network hostname. Alternatively, you can place your computer in the [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29), but this will allow all external ports to see your computer, and is not recommended as it will require much better security to protect your computer.